# How to add datagrid records to database?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which contains the list of students from my database table tblstudent. I have putted a textbox or maybe checkbox inside the datagrid to check if this students are present or not in the class, if they are present then I would input "P" in the datagrid textbox or "A" if they are absent. The problem is that I don't know how to put this records from datagrid into my another database table "tblLogs". Can somebody provide an idea for me? I'm still a newbie in WPF C# and much help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first answer for me (and the easiest one but not recommended) is to scan the gridview one by one and insert data int the database one by one using loops

```
Gridview.Rows.Cells[i].Text.ToString();
```

The second would be creating a datatable, the datatable would hold your gridview elements and then insert the whole datatable in the database using for each statement

```
 foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a textbox inside data grid. Data grid cell itself allows you to put any text that you want. And after that you can easily access the value of any cell as below

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkboxid")).Checked)
   {
     //student is present
   }            
   else //student is absent

   //create insert query here and execute it
}
```